# using .index() inside a hover()

Tags: jquery, indexing, hover

I'm having some trouble with using the `.index()` inside of a `.hover()` function.  Thanks for any help.

```
    $("#myUL li").hover(    
        function () {

            //this logs a li element as it should
            $(this).log();

            //this reports that it's not a valid function, why?
            $("#myUL").index(this).log();

            //when i do it this way...
            var foo = $("#myUL").index(this);
            //this returns -1.  Why can't it find the li?
            $(foo).log();

        },
        function () {
        }
    );
```

If it makes a difference, this is the code I'm using for the `.log()` function:

```
jQuery.fn.log = function (msg) {
    console.log("%s: %o", msg, this);
return this;
};
```

:edit: per the comment, here is the html:

```
    <ul id="myUL">
      <li>
        <div><img src="images/img1.jpg"/></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div><img src="images/img2.jpg"/></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div><img src="images/img3.jpg"/></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: sure Ghommey - thanks for the response.  I have added the html - see my edit above
":edit: per the comment, here is the html:"

Answer (score 1):

Normally the api of jQuery is to chain things. That means that in the usual case, at the end of a native jQuery function or plugin, it returns itself. ( via `return this;` ). This is what allows jQuery to use chaining. Since the previous function returns the original object, the next function that you run in the chain is *also* run on the original object.

In the case of the `$.index()` function, it returns a value. That value is an integer that represents its index. There is no `log()` function on a native integer. Chainability occurs when the preceding function returns the type of value that can have the next function invoked on it. (e.g. `"string".substring(1).indexOf('i')`)

In your code you might do:

```
var $myUL = $("#myUL"),
    foo   = $myUL.index(this);

$myUL.get(foo).log();
```